# Real time parse of midi input - Rhythmic differentiation

Tags: java, real-time

I am developing a real-time drum composing application with JAVA. The main issue I am trying to counter is to determine what is the rhythmic value of the note. I am having accuracy issues because I am considering even 32th notes in a metronome of 100bpm. This gives interval among notes of 75 ms. I am not 100% sure that the theoritical approach of considering time segments and assigning a rhythmical value can be scaled to every bpm or time interval.
Do you think it is doable, by also taking into consideration the human factor of playing? I guess this is a very specific/empirical question that goes for guys that developed similar apps.

Comment: A good performer will not miss his rhythm even by a 32th, and even at faster tempos (but that's a **good** performer :) On the other hand, Java is not suited to realtime timing-sensitive tasks. There are no guarantees given. If you can't timestamp each midi event upstream of Java, you'll never make this work reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Java is not a suitable language for real-time operations, and if accuracy of timing is so important for you this means you should not use Java directly(at least). Especially the non-deterministic behaviour of *garbage collection* complicates matters on the Java side for real time applications.

Comment: I am considering of moving the project to a c/c++ environment using CLAM. Since there is some work to be translated, I need to be sure that JAVA will have problems(very bad phrasing here!).

Comment: For the timing accuracy/determinism you need, I would definitely go with something like C/C++ rather than Java, if possible.